# Python. VSCode + SSH Как запускать скрипт от имени суперпользователя?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Изменения и упрощение старого вопроса ! Есть приложение на Python, захожу на VM (`Ubuntu 20`), выполняю `sudo su`, запускаю скрипт. При этом удаляется и создается файл `output.txt`. Открываю тот же скрипт в VSC, запускаю от имени того же пользователя - при попытке удаления файла получаю ошибку **Permission denied**. В нете вычитал что нужно добавить опцию sudo = true в файл launch.json, не помогло. Вопрос - как запустить sudo ?

Comment: Вы задаётесь неправильным вопросом. Правильный — как сделать так, чтобы приложение могло работать без лишних привилегий

Comment: Готово, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Теперь у вас заголовок и текст противоречат друг другу, ну и перед этим закономерно возникает другой вопрос — зачем приложению вообще понадобились какие-то привилегии

Comment: Противоречия ... я склоняюсь к первоначальному варианту скорее - нужно как-то повысить привилегии при удаленном запуске. Логика работы такова что в процессе работы нужно остановить один процесс, подкинуть новые конфиги и запустить процесс заново, почистить временные файлы и пр. Так как процесс запускался от имени рута, то без повышения привилегий остановить его не могу.

Comment: «Так как процесс запускался от имени рута»  — зачем?

Comment: Это комплекс, сторонняя разработка, так вот запускается.

Comment: Тогда по теме вопроса — как вы запускаете «локально», как вы запускаете «из VSCode», в чём отличия между этими двумя запусками и зачем в принципе что-то пытаться запускать из VSCode?

Comment: Захожу на VM, "sudo su" и запускаю файл main.py - ЛОКАЛЬНО на машине, все ОК. В VSCode установлен SSHremote (не помню точное название), запуск (или отладку) произвожу из VSC на винде, программа выполняется на VM (Ubuntu) - УДАЛЕННЫЙ ЗАПУСК. Очень удобно при пошаговой отладке, не смог ее настроить на PyCharm, пришлось перейти на VSC. При запуске все ответы программы отображаются в VSC, не нужно переключаться. Ну и текст программы с точками останова и значениями переменных в режиме отладки.